# Django model method to count method flag of foreignkeys

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models `Assessment` and `Answer` with a OnetoMany relationship.

`models.py`

```
class Assessment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

    def _all_answers_completed(self):
         pass
         #some how get all related answers
         #then see if "completed" = true
         #if all = true then return true
         #if any = false then return false
    completed = property(_all_answers_completed)


class Answer(models.Model):
    assessment = models.ForeignKey(Assessment, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score_risk = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    score_impact = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    score_occurrance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Answer to Question:{} for Assessment {}".format(self.question, self.assessment)

    def _is_answered(self):
        if self.score_risk > 0 and self.score_impact >0  and self.score_occurrance > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    completed = property(_is_answered)
```

I want to set the assessment method `completed` based on the related answers property `answer.completed`

I just don't know how to do this or do I have to do this in a view via looping through a queryset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the "answers" related to the current "Assessment" object and then simply loop through them to find if all answers are completed or not.

Your code should look something similar to this (untested):

```
def _all_answers_completed(self):
    answers = self.answer_set.all()
    for answer in answers:
        if not answer.completed:
            return False
    return True
```

Here `self.answer_set` will get all the `Answer` objects who have a foreign key of the current `Assesment` object (i.e. `self`). You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/)

Comment: You can do it with a simple `.exists()` query: `self.answer_set.filter(completed=False).exists()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the suggestion, but actually you can't use that query. `completed` is a property and thus does not exist in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the great help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [backward-related-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).